# "Curate from" meaning in the following sentence

Tags: word-meaning

What is the meaning of "curate from"in the following sentence:

> Some of the news agencies we curate from: AP, NYT

I searched the word "curate" but didn't find what makes sense here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A curator in a museum must *select* and *present* artefacts to show.

So to curate means to select and present something.  This organisation chooses news stories from AP, NYT and others and presents them, probably on its website.  It doesn't write its own new reports, it publishes chosen reports from other sources, which it may format to its own style.

Answer (score 1):

It means they collected and organized information from their sources (AP, NYT).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @Community Please don't use that canned response.  It doesn't make sense to ask for "working code".